# Old results from Android wifi.getScanResults()

Tags: android, android-wifi

On my Droid 2, the wifi.getScanResults() seems to return old values for a short time.

This means while I am at home, wifi.getScanResults() will show my home network. If I drive down the street several miles away, wifi.getScanResults() will still show my home network for the first 1 or 2 tries. On the third try my home network is gone.

Question:
Is there a way to get only the most recent wifi.getScanResults()?

Possible options:

- If the .level of the ScanResult is
  minimum, assume that it is out of
  range.
- Somehow clear the ScanResults,
  using an undocumented API.

I have some code like this:

```
context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
wifi.startScan();
```

...

```
if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        {
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found so far is to turn off WiFi and then turn it back on, since this results in a completely new scan:

```
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Adds a bit of delay, but works (finds a lot of APs near me).

Answer (score 1):

You do get the last result. If it's outdated, you can [start a new scan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29) and set a [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to get a new list.